# Error when compiling and running a program into another program

Tags: c, linux

I want to make a program in c that compiles and runs another program. I wrote this code and it returns this:

> robi@Robi:~$ ./comp test.c
>
> gcc: fatal error: no input files
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> Error

I compile it like this:

> gcc -Wall -o  comp Compilare.c

and run it like this:

> ./comprun test.c

*test.c is this*

```
#include<stdio.h>

    int main(){
            printf("Ana are mere");
            return 0;
    }
```

*The code:*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
        char comanda[100];
        strcpy(comanda,"gcc -o run");
        strcat(comanda,argv[1]);
        if(WEXITSTATUS(system(comanda) == 0))
                execl("./run","./run",NULL);
        printf("Error");
        return 0;
}
```

How can I make it run without errors?

Comment: try adding a space after `run` in `strcpy`

Comment: Use a debugger and/or debug print statements to examine the program as it executes. You should be able to find the problem easily by yourself if you did even very basic debugging.

Comment: You are running `gcc -o runtest.c` instead of `gcc -o run test.c`. Just add the space and it should be fine.

Comment: along with the problems exposed in the other comments,  this line: `printf("Ana are mere");` will only output to the `stdout` buffer,  You want output through that buffer to the display, so the line should be: `printf("Ana are mere\n");`  or `printf("Ana are mere");  fflush( stdout );`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `gcc` command you invoke inside the program looks like this: `gcc -o runtest.c`, i.e., it attempts to compile no input to an output binary called `runtest.c`. You need a space at the end of your string literal: `"gcc -o run"` -> `"gcc -o run "`